# The use of the word "closet"

Tags: word-usage, connotation

On [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/closet),  one of *closet
8's definitions is:

> Used to refer to a state of secrecy or concealment, especially about one's homosexuality.

Though by memory, I remember that it may have been used in other examples. For example, would the following sentence make sense:

> He is a closet gardener.

Does it mean that this person enjoys gardening, but doesn't tell anybody about his enjoyment of gardening?

If this usage of the word *closet* is correct, is it possible that it would offend anybody, or does it seem alright to use?

Comment: Why do you think *He is a closet gardener* would offend anyone? (And yes it's using the word 'closet' correctly  and yes the definition you give is correct.)

Comment: Sure it is used for other situations, but it remains a sardonic reference to the stigma that was once attached to gays. So unless he's growing pansies, I'd not use if for gardening. You could use it to point out that some endeavor is beyond the pale according to the mores of society.

Comment: My pinion: I see nothing wrong with it. Ironically, I've often heard people refer to themselves as "closet [fill in the blank]."

Comment: @RichardKayser Salutations! There, I filled in the blank: closet wordsmith.

Comment: @PeterPoint Greetings! And you are a closet comedian. And I mean that in a good way. You're funny. :-)

Comment: Well, there are some terms that one is allowed to use in reference to oneself, but it is impolite, offensive, and/or politically incorrect to use in reference to somebody else — for example, "fat" and "old" (and — dare I mention it? — the "N-word"). I would avoid using "closet" in this way because some people might interpret it as saying that the person has a shameful secret.

Comment: Offence will only be taken from the activity identified, so "homosexuality" or "gardening". Where that in itself is not offensive, neither will the closet version be.

There is a slight possibility “closet” could make an offensive term worse but so long as the thing itself is inoffensive, the closet version will do nothing but perhaps add a little spice - of which "closet gardener" is a perfect example.

Comment: "He is a closet gardener" is a valid statement, and means about what you suggest.  It does not imply anything about his sexuality.  However, bear in mind that there are some people who are bound and determined to see a slur or insult in every statement you might make.

Comment: @PhilSweet - If he were in a dangerous biker gang but enjoyed growing flowers at home, he might well be a closet gardener with respect to his fellow bikers.

Comment: And it should be noted that many marijuana producers are "closet gardeners".

Answer (score 4):

> especially about one's homosexuality.

The use of *especially* here means it's at least sometimes used about something other than homosexuality. (One example that is actually the opposite is that in the bisexual community the pressure to pretend to be either gay or straight is often called "picking a closet", with pretending to be gay seen as being as much "in the closet" as pretending to be straight).

> is it possible that it would offend anybody

Only if either the statement without "closet" would offend, or if the suggestion of secrecy expressed another way would offend.